# count(*) is so slow in MyISAM table

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

I have a big database 5GB that most of its database engines are MyISAM,
Server RAM is about 20GB but query_cache and other configs are sets as default (16MB).
MySQL version is 5.7.27, I got an old backup of the database that is 3.5GB and when I run the query in my local It's so faster than production.

```
FLUSH QUERY CACHE;
RESET QUERY CACHE;
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE 
    count(*)
FROM
    company_reports rep
    LEFT JOIN system_users usr ON rep.user_id = usr.id
    LEFT JOIN company_rep_subjects sbj ON rep.subject_id = sbj.id
    INNER JOIN company_partners cus ON rep.partner_id = cus.id
    LEFT JOIN project_con_messages mes ON rep.message_id = mes.id
    LEFT JOIN company_par_user_settings pus ON cus.id = pus.partner_id 
    AND 1 = pus.user_id 
WHERE
    1=1 -- or other where and will generate by ACL and advanced search
```

I disabled cache

```
 query_cache_limit = 0
 query_cache_size = 0
```

I don't know why this query needs about 13s in production to get counts.
Is there any optimization suggestion? My RAM is free so how many cache settings is better to I allocate to query_cache.

IMPORTANT: Migrating to InnoDB is in my mind but I don't know why this query is so faster in my local,
Is there any Lock System that may prevent MySQL to count records faster in production? It tested even when our system was not in progress and in out of working time.

My local system is not MYSQL 5.7.27 and I'm using 10.1.38-MariaDB.

Here is EXPLAIN in my local

```
1   SIMPLE  cus index   PRIMARY PRIMARY 3       62293   Using index
1   SIMPLE  rep ref partner_id  partner_id  3   MYDBNAME.cus.id 13
```

In Production:

"Why they are not same!" Local is Mariadb 10 (2 rows) and Production is MYSQL 5.7.27 (6 rows)

[image]

EDIT: After sync local indexes with production now local is slow! That is good and I found out why speed in production is slow and which indexes missed.
I should add two index in production, read comments.

New EXPLAIN in local:

```
1   SIMPLE  cus index   PRIMARY companyname 362     63490   Using index
1   SIMPLE  rep ref partner_id  partner_id  3   ebrahim.cus.id  5   
1   SIMPLE  pus ref partner_id_2,user_id    partner_id_2    3   ebrahim.cus.id  2   Using where
```

I don't know why my local using companyname for index if I force it to use PRIMARY there was no change in speed but don't know why currently EXPLAINS are diffrent although INDEXES are synced.

**EDIT: After I increased buffer_key_size to 4G and added partner_id and user_id as a Composite Index and Unique and run ANALYSE on all query tables speed increased to 6.7s.**

[image]

```
join_buffer_size=>262144
key_buffer_size=>4294967296
myisam_sort_buffer_size=>8388608
net_buffer_length=>16384
read_buffer_size=>131072
preload_buffer_size=>32768

query_alloc_block_size 8192
query_cache_limit 1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit 4096
query_cache_size 16777216
```

**SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%'**

```
bulk_insert_buffer_size
8388608
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size
134217728
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown
ON
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct
25
innodb_buffer_pool_filename
ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances
1
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup
ON
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size
134217728
innodb_change_buffer_max_size
25
innodb_change_buffering
all
innodb_log_buffer_size
16777216
innodb_sort_buffer_size
1048576
join_buffer_size
262144
key_buffer_size
4294967296
myisam_sort_buffer_size
8388608
net_buffer_length
16384
preload_buffer_size
32768
read_buffer_size
131072
read_rnd_buffer_size
262144
sort_buffer_size
262144
sql_buffer_result
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English

Comment: I am unclear what you are trying to do. Do you want a count of pus.access is null and a count of pus.access in (1,2,3)?

Comment: @P.Salman I edited my query, Where depends on user access and advanced search and is a few different cases with different values.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...... so we can all see where INDEXES are missing.  If you are not familiar with EXPLAIN, google search for mysql explain tutorial, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I edit my question and added it

Comment: Please post the EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE yourquery..... from MariaDB for comparison.  The queries appear to be different when looking at the EXPLAIN results.

Comment: @WilsonHauck OMG, I checked all indexes and found out here is a difference in company_par_user_settings, In production partner_id and user_id are two indexes but in my local are one index and unique.if I sync my local same as production it become slow same as production. Thanks Wilson.

Comment: What is the purpose of 'AND 1 = pus.user_id WHERE 1 =1  at the end of your query?  Could this be causing the EXPLAIN to show you are processing 100% of 62,780 rows on the first line from TABLE named cus.  The key is to reduce rows qualifying to be processed.

Comment: @WilsonHauck we list reports of partners, every user may set some settings for partners so 1 = pus.user_id is there to get only records that related to the current user, 1=1 in WHERE is there when a user is FULL ACCESS and it may replace with pub.access in (1,2,3), in addition users may search based on other fields such as partners or subject... .Any Idea?

Comment: You have to decide whether Local 2 rows or Production 6 rows are correct.  We will go from there.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I want to go with 6 rows. after applying index and increase buffer_key_size its speed increased now.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I edited my post with new EXPLAIN.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile where we have FREE downloadable Utility Scripts, additional Analysis Services and contact info for additional assistance.

Answer (score 0):

- It is not necessarily better to have a large `query_cache_size`.  When any modification occurs to a table, all entries (in the QC) for that table are removed.  The bigger the QC, the longer this takes.  `50M` is a reasonable max.
- The non-QC caching needed involves all the tables in the query -- index blocks need to go into the `key_buffer` and data blocks need to be cached by the OS.  Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';` on both machines.
- The 13s on the busy production system may involve cache misses that did not happen on the less-busy other machine.
- Is the count correct?  There are a lot of seemingly-useless `JOINs`.  These may be inflating the `COUNT(*)` unexpectedly.

The answer is probably this:

The Optimizer code in MariaDB and MySQL have diverged.  It looks like MariaDB decided (hopefully correctly) that most of the tables were not relevant to the query.

I suggest you rewrite the query to use only `cus` and `rep` and run it on the MySQL production machine.  Then see if you get the same results as the current 6-table query.  And see if the query runs much faster.

(A side note...)  In the long run, MyISAM is going away.  You should plan on moving to InnoDB.

Comment: I edited my post with new information.It seems settings are defaults! I just increased key_buffer_size. Some joins will be involved after user used the advanced search.